# Jekyll front matter variable not being set in intermediate layout?

Tags: jekyll

In my default layout, I'm referencing a variable `{{page.headline}}`, and am referencing it as follows:

```
# _layouts/default.html
{{page.headline}}

# index.md
---
layout: default
headline: Great site
---

# _layouts/post.html
---
layout: default
headline: Great articles
---

# _posts/some-post.md
---
layout: post
headline: Great post # just for testing, and omitted when setting in post layout
---
```

The headline variable at the index--at Level 1--works as expected, and also at Level 3, in a specific post. But when I set "Great articles" in the post layout (and remove the variable setting from the front matter of `some-post.md`), nothing renders in the default layout's variable placeholder.

In other words, in the post layout, I don't see "Great articles" *or* "Great site," so it's like the initial variable setting of "Great site" in the default layout--which the post layout references--is being overwritten, but not replaced.

Yet this works at the third level with `some-post.md`--setting `headline` here, where the specific post uses the post layout, and the post layout itself uses default, *does* cause `page.headline` to be set to "Great post."

Should this work in the way I'm hoping for here? To set a variable in the front matter of a second layout that is based upon a first? (And again it's weird that it works at the bottom level, with the post itself.) Thanks.

(In reality I don't want to set it at the third level on each post, since it's just a generic "Articles" header--I'm including that here because of it working at that level, as explained above.)

Comment: what version of Jekyll are you using? Run `bundle exec jekyll -v` to check

Comment: All my gemz be current. Any idea why the variable isn't being set (or won't display)? The strange part is that it works at the post level (3-deep).

Comment: *I'm guessing* this behavior is because the `page` variable namespace is only for documents in the site. (Hence works with `index.md` and `some-post.md` in the example.) and layouts do not respond to that namespace.

Comment: A similar feature was added in Jekyll 3.5 where in layout front matter variables can be used in the templates. But I haven't tried it myself..

Comment: That sounds logical. Maybe I'll see about the new feature, or accomplish this some other way. Thanks. :)

Comment: By the way, do you think it's less common to have an initial index/landing page for posts? I checked out a few themes, and I think based on those along with the main site docs, it's more commonly expected to include a listing of posts on the main/home page, and link *directly* to posts from there.

Comment: Its upto you to decide how best to design your site. After all its the `uniqueness` about a site that impresses its visitors..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to reference the variable via the layout, and not the page, as described [here](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4123).

So, reference the variable in the layout as `{{ layout.headline }}` instead of `{{ page.headline }}`, and this can now be set via the front matter of an inheriting template (i.e., a template that itself specifies a parent template in its own front matter: `layout: default`).